# Getting "not responding" errors from other apps while playing my game

Tags: android

I'm currently making a game for Android and it's all nice and working, but during my game sometimes errors pop up about other apps (like Twitter/Facebook or some HTC Sense related processes) not responding.

Am I doing something wrong with my game that those apps don't get enough CPU or RAM or what could that be?

Hints are highly appreciated, as I don't want my players to be disturbed by this.

Thanks!

Comment: Sure sounds like CPU starvation. Are you running any threads at higher than normal priorities? Next time you get one of those dialogs, ensure your phone is connected to your PC and run 'adb pull /data/anr/traces.txt' and link the content here.

Comment: No higher than normal priorities set, I just let my game redraw as fast as possible which is 60fps due to hardware limitations. Next time I will catch one of those errors I will do what you told me.

Comment: Here it is: http://pastebin.com/KftUMQ94